# Hibernate: How to get only result objects whose count value are greater than a threshold

Tags: hibernate, hql

This is my query_string. It delivers all persons including count(persAccsBOs). This string works.

```
hql_query_string = ""
+ "select distinct pers, count(persAccsBOs) as anzBo from Person as pers"
+ " inner join pers.personenAttribute as persAttr inner join persAttr.pa_pk.attribut as pAttr"
+ " inner join pers.accounts as persAccs"
+ " inner join persAccs.berechtigungsobjekte as persAccsBOs"
+ " where pAttr.name= :attrName"
+ " and persAttr.wert= :attrValue"
+ " group by pers";
```

Now i want to get only persons whose count(persAccsBOs) is greater than a threshold. This doesnt work:

```
hql_query_string = ""
+ "select distinct pers, count(persAccsBOs) as anzBo from Person as pers"
+ " inner join pers.personenAttribute as persAttr inner join persAttr.pa_pk.attribut as pAttr"
+ " inner join pers.accounts as persAccs"
+ " inner join persAccs.berechtigungsobjekte as persAccsBOs"
+ " where pAttr.name= :attrName"
+ " and persAttr.wert= :attrValue"
+ " and count(persAccsBOs) >=  :threshold"
+ " group by pers";
```

I get the error message:

> 14:55:27.121 [main] DEBUG
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 139 logExceptions -
>   could not extract ResultSet [n/a] java.sql.SQLException: Invalid use
>   of group function

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexander,

I believe this will work:

```
hql_query_string = ""
+ "select distinct pers, count(persAccsBOs) as anzBo from Person as pers"
+ " inner join pers.personenAttribute as persAttr inner join persAttr.pa_pk.attribut as pAttr"
+ " inner join pers.accounts as persAccs"
+ " inner join persAccs.berechtigungsobjekte as persAccsBOs"
+ " where pAttr.name= :attrName"
+ " and persAttr.wert= :attrValue"
+ " group by pers"
+ " having count(persAccsBOs) >=  :threshold";
```

Conditions on aggregated fields must be made with the having clause, not inside the where clause.

Comment: any suggestion for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665737/group-by-count-query-sql-to-hql